# Facebook Ads API access without becoming PMD

Tags: facebook, ads, platform

I would like to run Facebook ads through the Ads API programatically. I believe I need to apply for becoming a Facebook PMD to get access to the API.

Question:
(1) Is there a way to access Facebook' Ads API through someone else's API (some other PMDs)

(2) Is there a way to retrieve the campaign statistics through APIs without the PMD status?

Answer (score 1):

1. From talking to some friends that are a relatively new PMD Facebook does not want  to add to many PMD and are actually considering enabling PMDs to offer APIs to non-PMD developers. 
   I have not seen the first company do this publicly, but I would rech out to medium sized PMDs to see if they are open to this.
2. Not really, without being a PMD you wont be able to access data via Ads API.

Comment: Is this still true? No access to Ads API without being a PMD?